# Failed to send SSL Close message when using KafkaPublish processor to write to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, kafka-producer-api, sasl

I am using KafkaPublish processor to publish messages to a kafka topic secured using SASL_SSL security protocol (we are not using Kerberos).

I get the below error:

```
WARN Failed to send SSL Close message  
(org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the 
remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at 
  org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.flush(SslTransportLayer.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:172)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:718)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doClose(Selector.java:746)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:734)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:532)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:628)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am able to publish into the topic from command prompt.

When i use `SASL_SSL` in KafkaPublish Kerberos service name is a mandatory field. But since we are not using Kerberos what value should I set for this field?

[image: Configure Processor]

When i set the dynamic properties sasl.mechanism and sasl.jaas.configuration I get invalid configuration parameter warning.

Am I missing any configurations? Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of KafkaPublish are you using? I believe you need at least PublishKafka_0_11 or PublishKafka_1_0 to use SASL with a mechanism different than Kerberos

Comment: Thank you Mickael. That helped. I was using PublishKafka earlier. Now i changed to PublishKafka_1_0 and it works fine.

Comment: Great, I've posted a proper answer, feel free to accept it if that solves your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NiFi's PublishKafka only support SASL with mechanisms other than Kerberos since version 0_11.

So you want to be sure you use PublishKafka_0_11 or PublishKafka_1_0 if you need to use SASL Plain for example.